# DotNetOpenAuth and multiple Subdomains

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, dotnetopenauth

I have a question that I cant seem to get a straight answer to anywhere on the web.

Can DotNetOpenAuth be used to handle single sign on for multiple subdomains, never mind what app or platform, can i have a provider service that after the user has first signed in on one of the sub domains, he wont have to sign in again.

I dont care about facebook/twitter integration etc.  which it appears to me that DotNetOpenAuth seems to mainly be used for??

Also, does anyone have a sample implementation of such a provider?

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say *sub* domains, do you mean the third level domain name (the 'www' part)? If so, you can do that entirely without any special library or protocol. Just set your user session cookies to apply to the second level domain name and all sub domains will automatically have visibility into it.

Across second level domain names requires a protocol, and yes, DotNetOpenAuth can help here. If you download the .zip from sourceforge the samples include two SSO samples that may help you there.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

say I have a.mydomain.com which runs a MVC asp.net app.. and b.mydomain.com, which is running a php app.  Is it enough to just use the user session cookie?  can a php app read a .net cookie?

Comment: In that case you'd need to set a custom cookie format that they both understand because you'd define it. But yes, OpenID between the two is another way to go, although I wouldn't say it's easier.

Comment: I would like to keep it as simple (in terms of the amount of code) as possible so would rather just use openID i think.

Do you know of any examples online of implementing this or something similiar with dotnetopenauth.

Im really struggling to find much info on this

Comment: I think amount of code is smaller with a shared cookie, actually. And so long as you're signing (and probably encrypting) the cookie, more easily secured than adding OpenID endpoints to both web sites. Don't get me wrong, I think OpenID is great, but for SSO between just two internal web sites it may be overkill. You have to think about locking down the OpenID RP and OP to only respond to each other, and that's not hard, but you have to know just how to do it and it may not be obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew! Im just thinking of the scalability of this and the possibility of other apps needing integration on the same or possibly different domains.   

Im just wondering, with OpenID and OpenAuth, should be these be hosted as a WCF service or just a website?

Comment: If web sites are calling each other, then yes, a web service would seem more appropriate.